# Crash in the Foundry

Tags: technical-issues, planescape-torment

I have a problem in this awesome game. I have all mods from the Gogcom's mod guide installed and my game crashes.

The crash is during the loading screen for the dormitories/tower in the foundry, no matter when it is done (before/after the join Foundry quests). The game just saves and crashes during load. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add more informations? Error messages, anything can help.

Comment: Standard CTD, no error messages but the windows 7 "App crashed, look for fix" one; and as the game retains draw control until closed, I cannot run VS10 debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by the Widescreen mod patch. De-apply, finish the quest, re-apply both windescreen and UI patches to go back to the initial state. Any content mod installed remains, so there is no need to re-apply.